# MixItUp plugin filter logic

Tags: jquery, sorting, filter

I'm developing a website with categorized product listing and I want to filter products out based on which categories user choose. Users should have an option to choose multiple categories. Starting point is to show all categories and no products. When you choose first category you get products from this category, when you choose second category you only get products which are listed in both categories.

I tried to use filterLogic: 'and' instead of filterLogic: 'or' but in that case nothing is showing at all.

My paramaters:

```
$('#products').mixitup({
    targetSelector: '.mix1',
    filterSelector: '.filter1',
    sortSelector: '.sort',
    buttonEvent: 'click',
    effects: ['fade'],
    listEffects: null,
    easing: 'snap',
    layoutMode: 'grid',
    targetDisplayGrid: 'inline-block',
    targetDisplayList: 'block',
    gridClass: '',
    listClass: '',
    transitionSpeed: 600,
    showOnLoad: 'none',
    sortOnLoad: false,
    multiFilter: true,
    filterLogic: 'or',
    resizeContainer: true,
    minHeight: 0,
    failClass: 'fail',
    perspectiveDistance: '3000',
    perspectiveOrigin: '50% 50%',
    animateGridList: true,
    onMixLoad: null,
    onMixStart: null,
    onMixEnd: null
});
```

I read mixitup docs but didn't find anything helpful for this particular situation.

What am I missing?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the mixitup demo here http://mixitup.io/demos/parks the drop down menus on the right seem to be what your after.